# Python: How to get URLs of tag filtered Instagram images

Tags: python, api, instagram

I'm wanting to search for Instagram photos by tag, and return their URLs. How would I go about getting the URL from each item(s) in 'filtered_media'?

```
filtered_media = api.tag_recent_media(1,1,'fox')
```

Comment: how do you get the data? what is this api object and how was it created?

Comment: INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID = 'API KEY'
INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET = 'SECRET KEY


api = InstagramAPI(client_id=INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
                   client_secret=INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET)

Comment: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly are you asking. I guess you are using the [python-instagram](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram) lib (also I'm just guessing from the syntax you refer to in the comment, you should write this kind of stuff in the question).  If so you'll be getting a list, you can just iterate over like the example in the lib:

```
for media in recent_media:
   print media.caption.text
```

for your specific question about the image url , I consulted the [api](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) (thanks for the link @r2mus) each list item would be a python dict. and you can call it like this:

```
for media in filtered_media:
   if media.type == 'image': # could also be a video or something else perhaps
      for img in media.images: # a sub list containing the different images in different resolutions
         print img.url
```

or if you are after a specific resolution (for example the standard one) you could directly:

```
for media in filtered_media:
   if media.type == 'image':
       print media.images.standard_resolution.url
```

Comment: Sorry for the vague description. You are correct, I am using that lib. When trying that code, I get an error: if media.type == 'image':
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: My code (not including declerations of my access tokens/keys: '#Start up the API
api = InstagramAPI(client_id=INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,client_secret=INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET)

filtered_media =  api.tag_recent_media(1,1,'fox')

for media in filtered_media:
    if media.type == 'image':
        for img in media.images:
            print img.url'

Comment: so media is also an array and you could iterate over it the same way, just print (media) and post what you get

Answer (score 0):

You should build your query like this:

```
filtered_media = api.tag_recent_media(1,1,tag_name='fox')
```